# A synoynm for " to make up for"

Tags: word-request

Which word would be used instead of the phrasal verb " to make up for something"

For example :

> ...You have been given the wrong room. I hope you will accept a
>   complimentary meal in our restaurant to **make up for** your
>   inconvenience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[*compensate*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/compensate) would work:

> I hope you will accept a complimentary meal in our restaurant to compensate (for) your inconvenience.

I'm not sure if the version with or without "for" is better. [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=compensate+for+your%2C+compensate+your&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccompensate%20for%20your%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccompensate%20your%3B%2Cc0) suggests that "for" is more often used than not.